# Troubleshooting bootstrap nav and fluid rows - Currently non-responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, fluid-layout, nav

The reason why I'm using bootstrap is because of all of it's responsive design options.

But now I'm pulling my hair out since it's not behaving responsively, in spite of the fact that all of the css sheets (I believe) are embedded into the page headers.

There's two problems I've noticed:
1. The navbar does not consolidate itself for either the phone or the tablet
2. page components do not re-stack vertically when the window shrinks

In the web site I made [here](http://ineek.eu/index.php), both of these problems don't exist. I copied and pasted the code I used in the previous site for the new project I'm working on ([here](http://tardis.tcnj.edu/1/index.php)) but something is stopping it from working correctly.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing?

Comment: Make sure `bootstrap-responsive.min.css` is included after `bootstrap.min.css` - If you still have a problem you should use Bootply.com or JSFiddle to post your code and narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Skelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171456/skelly) noted, make sure you add the bootstrap responsive css after the bootstrap.min css.

Many of the blocks on this page with the grey background also have left and right padding which will also interfere with the bootstrap grid.

EG

```
.bg_grey_02 {
....
padding: 100px 20px 60px 20px;
...
}
```

I think you want to start by removing these. eg padding: 100px 0 60px 0;

Same thing for .bg_grey_01 and .bg_grey_03

Good luck